# Strange JS Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i got a really strange JS Error. 
I get following Error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null (Line 83)
```

Line 83 looks like:

```
 var image = '<img class="news_image_options"src="http://www.example.com'+news_feed.posts[i].attachment.url+'">';
```

Now the logical conclusion would be that the there is no url property in the json feed. But it is there, i swear. 
When i write the image-var in console.log I get following:

```
<img class="news_image_options" src="http://www.example.com/2017/01/153386O.jpg">
```

(The result I need!)

The strange thing is that sometimes (with some news) I get the error and sometimes not...

Comment: can you post some more code

Comment: We don't see enough code, here. Please build a code snippet. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Actually, to me this suggests `posts[i].attachment` doesn't exist. Is the news feed empty? Are you going off the end of the array?

Comment: *"The strange thing is that sometimes (with some news) I get the error and sometimes not..."* That indicates that not all posts have an `attachment`. Think about what you want to do for posts without attachments (i.e. where `news_feed.posts[i].attachment` doesn't exist).

Comment: @Carcigenicate if it didn't exist I would expect `Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`, rather than `null`

Comment: @Alnitak perhaps he initialises it to null when he defines his js object.

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh guys i am so silly...
The reason is that some news don't have a picture!

The reason i was confused was that the image variable contained the image-url from the picture from the news posted before...

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Now you should delete that question

Answer (score -1):

`Cannot read property 'url' of null` tells us that the value of `news_feed.posts[i].attachment` is `null` and not `undefined`.  This suggest that the value is set to null at some point, as by default, it would be `undefined`.

Comment: What makes you think the OP is generating the data? They might as well get it from some third-party service.